# Does the 14 day self-isolation period in the UK end if a travel-corridor starts during the 14-day self-isolation period?

Tags: uk, covid-19, quarantine

From 8th June there's been a [mandatory 14 day self-isolation](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk) period for people entering the UK. From 10th July, travellers from [some countries are exempted from the self-isolation](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors) via a travel-corridor. If more countries are added to the list of exemptions then the date for each country will be later than the 10th July.

If a traveller entered the UK from a country that is not on the exempt list and that country is added to the exempt list prior to the end of the 14 day self-isolation period does the self-isolation period end early?

For example, if an individual entered the UK from France on the 5th July, should they remain in isolation for 14 days or does the isolation end on the 10th when France is added to the list of exempt countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors

> Returning to England before 10 July 2020
>
> If you return to England from
> an exempt country before 10 July 2020, you should follow the rules
> that apply on the date you arrive in England.

Answer (score 8):

You will still have to finish the 14-day self-isolation requirement.

The [UK GOV exemption rules state](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors):

> ### Exemption rules
>
> **From 10 July 2020 you will not have to self-isolate when you arrive in
> England**, if you:
>
> - are travelling or returning from one of the countries with travel corridor exemption
> - have not been to or stopped in a country that’s not on the travel corridors exemption list in the previous 14 days

This does not apply to you since you started the self-isolation period/arrived in England before 10 July 2020 so you need to finish the 14 days.

Comment: Sorry that's wrong info. France is on the exemption list

Comment: It's vital to remember that England is only one of the countries in the UK and different regulations apply in the other countries of the UK

Comment: @rodgertyler France is indeed on the exemption list, but the exemption applies only to travelers who arrive in the UK on or after July 10, 2020. The OP's "example traveler" arrived on July 5, so the exemption does not apply. The UK Guidance cited in ex-user3761894"s answer comports exactly with Daniil's answer.